# Make AJAX Request on Blur for single Input

Tags: ajax, angularjs, forms

I'm pretty new to Angular and having a form like this (about 15 Inputs and Selects):

```
<div id="configForm" data-ng-controller="seutpController">
    <form name="configForm" data-ng-submit="update()" novalidate>
        <input id="id" type="hidden" data-ng-model="config.id" />
        <input id="company" type="text" data-ng-model="config.company" data-ng-blur="test()"/>
        <input id="street" type="text" data-ng-model="config.street" data-ng-blur="test()" />
    </form>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

### What's already working:

Making an AJAX Call on Submit which updates the Database with all values from the config object. No big Deal.

### What I'd like to do:

Making an AJAX Call (on Blur), but I'd like to send only the one key/value pair which was changed by the user like:

```
$http({
    url: 'api/setConfig.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'company': 'value'}
})
```

Do I have to send $event as function param like ng-blur="test($event)" and get the Elements Id and Value from there?

Thanks @ all!

### Edit

Is it a possible option using $watchCollection and watching on the $scope.config object?

Comment: The event itself is probably not interesting, but you could pass the field that has been blurred as a parameter to the `ng-blur` function, like `ng-blur('company')`. In your controller, then just validate this updated field and pass it along to the server in a `$http` call.

Comment: Was thinking of this already. Would work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: NP! Re: the $watchCollection question, this approach probably also works, but I think it will fire on every keystroke in the input fields. That would make it more complex to determine when the input field editing has finished and should be persisted to the backend. It's however probably a nice way to handle saves after say a 5 second timeout, if you want that kind of fault tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's probably best to send the $event, since that would be the most extendable solution. I've done something similar in the past:

```
<input name="title" ng-blur="ctrl.onFieldChanged($event)" type="text" ng-model="ctrl.title"/>
```

In my method, I named the input the same name as the ng-model its bound to, just for convenience. In the  controller, here's what I do:

```
this.onFieldChanged = function ($event) {
    var data = {};
    data[$event.currentTarget.name] = self[$event.currentTarget.name];

    $http({
      url: '...',
      method: 'POST',
      data: data
    });
  };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did it already the same way but it startet feeling a bit dirty sending the whole $event as param for just getting the keys name ('company').

Answer (score 0):

In the view

`onblur=test(config.company,'name')`

In the controller

```
    $scope.test = function(value,name){

             $http({
      url: '...',
      method: 'POST',
      name: value
    });
```

Hope it helps